# Tkinter/Matplotlib inconsistent behaviour between debugging and 'release'

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, matplotlib-animation

## Preliminaries

- Python: 3.11.1 x64
- tkinter: 8.6
- matplotlib: 3.6.2
- VsCode 1.77.2 on Windows 10 21H2

## Summary

I have a simple app that plots a graph on a tkinter canvas, records the image and then restores said image using copy_from_bbox and restore region respectively. When I debug and step through the code, I can see the graph appear, then get cleared and then get restored. If I run the app normally none of these steps seem to happen. What am I doing wrong?

## Code

The code is complete and should just paste and run

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import time

root = tkinter.Tk()

# Step 1: create a plot and copy from bbox
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.draw()
bg = canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.axes[0].bbox)
time.sleep(3)

# Step 2: clear the axes
fig.axes[0].clear()
canvas.draw()
time.sleep(3)

# Step 3: restore the plot
canvas.restore_region(bg)
canvas.blit(fig.axes[0].bbox)
canvas.flush_events()

# Step 4: enter tkinter loop
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that all tkinter updates are handled inside the `mainloop()`, so any updates (step 1 and 2) before the two `sleep(3)` are overwritten by the last update (step 3) before `mainloop()`.  So you can only see the last update when the window is shown.  Add `root.update()` before `sleep(3)` to force the updates.

Comment: I guess this should be the answer ^

Comment: Why not answer your own question based on the comment of acw1668?

Comment: I think it still doesn't explain why pausing in debugger behaves differently. Presumably the debugger calls some equivalent of root.update(?)